# Executing CGI from PHP with a password protection? / PHP Apache not running curl_init(); in web, only in CLI

Tags: php, html, authentication, curl, cgi

I'm working on project where I have a billing server (Server 1) and a control panel server (Server 2 / Virtualmin) where the billing system has to execute a script on Server 2 that accepts variables, but the file on server 2 requires authentication.

I was able to achieve what I wanted using a shell command on a different server like so:

```
wget --http-user=root --http-passwd=pass --no-check-certificate https://example.com:10000/virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=create-domain&domain=example.net&pass=123&default-features
```

The problem with this, is the billing server **is only able to execute a specific PHP file**, and the server does not have wget installed, so I cannot do it with shell_exec.

I attemted using PHP cURL, however I don't really know how to use it, and it didn't work. This is what I tried:

```
$serverip = "example.com:10000";
$domain = "example.net";
$password = "123";

$ch = curl_init("https://$serverip/virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=create-domain&domain=$domain&pass=$password&default-features");

$userpwd = 'root:pass';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If there are any more details you need let me know, I'd be glad to give more information. Thanks in advance, I know this seems very bizarre.

**EDIT ONE**
This is the new code I tried, still isn't working.

```
<html>
<h1>Provision Test</h1><hr />

<?php

$domain = "example.net";
$password = "123";
$serverip = "example.com:10000";

$ch = curl_init();

$userpwd = 'root:pass';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://{$serverip}/virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=create-domain&domain={$domain}&pass={$password}&default-features");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>

</html>
```

**EDIT TWO**
It appears to execute the above code (Edit 1) fine, but only via a CLI, and when attempted via a web interface, nothing happens, the script just stops once it hits curl_init();. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @AlexLunix I've tried looking into the HTTPAUTH, you can see the code I tried above. It doesn't seem to be working, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Now you've lost the secure part from http. Have a look also on how to use curl to connect via `https`.

Comment: Well, it appears the above edited script works when executed via CLI on one of my servers, however does not work when accessed via the web. Appears to be a different problem than I originally anticipated. Any ideas?